# Covert String to DateTime in request

Tags: php, laravel

Now, the value that i get in `request` is in `2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324` format. I want to convert this to `datetime` in format `2021-06-08`. How to convert this?

```
 $order['pickup_date']= DateTime::parse($request->input('pickup_date'))->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

The error I get is "The data given was invalid".

Comment: Can you explain what "does not work" means? Are you getting an error? What is your expected outcome vs your actual outcome? Also, Laravel has `Carbon` available for Date/Time manipulation: https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: The error I get is "The data given was invalid".

Comment: I get *"Call to undefined method DateTime::parse()"* when I try to run your code, but `new DateTime('2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324')` works just fine, then *"Call to undefined method DateTime::isoFormat()"*. I think you're mistaking `DateTime` with `Carbon`, since `Carbon::parse('2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324')->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD')` works just fine...

Answer (score 2):

What about Carbon?

```php
Carbon::parse($request->input('pickup_date'))->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: @Milayo have you got any validation?

Comment: i only put required in validation

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Laravel.You can use `Carbon`

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u',$request->input('pickup_date'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

For your ref format abbreviations

```
d - The day of the month (from 01 to 31)
D - A textual representation of a day (three letters)
j - The day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31)
l (lowercase 'L') - A full textual representation of a day
N - The ISO-8601 numeric representation of a day (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday)
S - The English ordinal suffix for the day of the month (2 characters st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j)
w - A numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday)
z - The day of the year (from 0 through 365)
W - The ISO-8601 week number of year (weeks starting on Monday)
F - A full textual representation of a month (January through December)
m - A numeric representation of a month (from 01 to 12)
M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)
n - A numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros (1 to 12)
t - The number of days in the given month
L - Whether it's a leap year (1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise)
o - The ISO-8601 year number
Y - A four digit representation of a year
y - A two digit representation of a year
a - Lowercase am or pm
A - Uppercase AM or PM
B - Swatch Internet time (000 to 999)
g - 12-hour format of an hour (1 to 12)
G - 24-hour format of an hour (0 to 23)
h - 12-hour format of an hour (01 to 12)
H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)
i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)
s - Seconds, with leading zeros (00 to 59)
u - Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2)
e - The timezone identifier (Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores)
I (capital i) - Whether the date is in daylights savings time (1 if Daylight Savings Time, 0 otherwise)
O - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours (Example: +0100)
P - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours:minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)
T - Timezone abbreviations (Examples: EST, MDT)
Z - Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is negative (-43200 to 50400)
c - The ISO-8601 date (e.g. 2013-05-05T16:34:42+00:00)
r - The RFC 2822 formatted date (e.g. Fri, 12 Apr 2013 12:01:05 +0200)
U - The seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
```

Ref:https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Comment: where to put my $request value in this format?

Comment: look like you are not sending exact format you have mentioned  in .it should be 2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324

Comment: to verify you can test this  \Carbon\Carbon::parse("2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324")->format('Y-m-d ')

Comment: \Carbon\Carbon::parse("2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324")->format('Y-m-d ') this one is fine, but if I put request, it show "the data given was invalid" error.

Comment: it means request has invalid format so once dd($request->input('pickup_date')) and show what you get in it

Comment: or you can dd($request->all()); and post what you get

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I really don't get it.

What is wrong with writing clean code?

Why you can not use simple PHP functions?

No matter if you are using any calendar/validating input on the frontend still backend data validations will help you.

Here is a **simple PHP solution**, in which you can check invalid data also:

```
$dateInput = '2021-06-08 00:31:25.168324'; //$request->input('pickup_date')
$date = date_create($dateInput);
// At this point you can test invalid data, provided by user.
if (!$date) {
  return 'Please provide a valid date';
}

$formattedDate = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
var_dump($formattedDate); // '2021-06-08'
```